# Youtube Upload Code suddenly prompt Credential Exception

Tags: youtube-api

I wrote a program to upload our racing videos continuously (loop through every five minutes to see whether a video is finished upload, if finished then start upload another race video)

It all works fine and just from yesterday, it suddenly give a credential exception. First I though it might be the google blocked me cause I uploaded too many videos?

So I tried our testing google account use the program to upload one video and it comes with the same error again?

Some body know anything might go wrong? To me the code is absolutely fine, It works for nearly a year and no body touched it.

I'm confused!

Crash point is --> call service.setUserCredentials( username, the_password)

Java exception thrown: com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService$InvalidCredentialsE
xception: Invalid credentials.

Answer (score 0):

It magically works today. I still don't know why, I think its google's problem down there end, so if anybody met this problem in the future, don't panic, go home and have tea, try tomorrow~~~